# Is there a way to set repository settinging through the Gitlab API?

Tags: gitlab

I'm aware there is a way to set (Application settings)[https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/settings.html] through the GitLab API, but is there a way to set settings for a repository?

Specifically, I am trying to set the integration settings for the Kubernetes plug-in, which are found under `https://gitlab.platformserviceaccount.com/lush-soa/service/REPO_NAME/services/kubernetes/edit`. I have read through the API documentation and am not seeing how this could be done, is there a way?